# Getting Data from MS Access located in Remote Server [VB.net]

Tags: vb.net, listview

Currently, I am successfully getting data from MS Access into listboxview from the local LAN.

We have another Access file in remote Server which we mapped as S drive i.e. S:\dbfile\test.accdb.  I am trying the below string to get the data from Remote Server.  However, the data is not populating and no errors throwing.

```
con = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=s:\dbfile\test.accdb")
```

below is the code using for populating listbox view

```
Sub datapopulate()

    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim command As OleDbCommand
    Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader
    'setup listview


    connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=s:\dbfile\test.accdb")
    connection.Open()
    'reading data from  table
    command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbllist", connection)
    data_reader = command.ExecuteReader

    'add data to listview
    If data_reader.HasRows Then
        While data_reader.Read

            Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
            newitem.Text = data_reader.GetValue(2) 'first column
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(3)) 'second column
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(5)) 'second column
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(6)) 'second column


            ListView1.Items.Add(newitem)

        End While
    End If

End Sub
```

Does any one has idea why the data is not populating?

Comment: Most likely it's using the default port for opening an oledbconnection and this port is blocked at a firewall somewhere. On an internal LAN this would not be a problem, but an external source it would show up even though the file is visible.

Comment: Does `connection.Open` succeed? If so, is `data_reader.HasRows` true or false?

Comment: @JoelEtherton Thank you for your reply. We are successfully opening the Access file directly without any issue but the problem is when i try to use the access file with vb.net. I think, the firewall may not be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Yes. It is succeed and data_reader.hasrows is true. Thank you.

Comment: @rocky09: If data_reader.HasRows is true then the data is populating. Does the process enter the while loop? Are the rows present but unpopulated?